# Laravel echo pusher не прослушивается канал фронт часть vue.В чем может проблема

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, echo

****Создал событие при создании записи нового сообщения**

---

```
<?php
namespace App\Events;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;
class Test implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;
   public  $message;
    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($message)
    {
        $this->message=$message;
    }
    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new Channel('message');
    }
}
```

- В контроллере вызвал событие.Данные отобразились в pusher debug-console

  use App\Events\Test;
  public  function save(Request $request){

  ```
      $message=new Message();

      $message->to=$request->contact_id;
      $message->from=Auth::user()->id;
      $message->text=$request->text;
      $message->save();
      Test::dispatch("new Test");
      return response()->json($message);
    }
  ```

  Для прослушивания использовал Echo laravel но данный код не срабатывает в консоль не чего не выводит .Из настроек раскоментировал в файле boorstart

  methods:{
              sendMessage(text){
                  if(!this.contact){
                      return
                  }
                  else{
                    axios.post('conversation/send',{
                        contact_id:this.contact.id,
                        text:text
                    }).then((response)=>{
                        this.$emit('new',response.data)
                      })

  ```
                  Echo.channel('message') .listen('Test',(e)=>{
                      alert('opp')
                      console.log(e);
                  });
              }
              //console.log(text)
          }
      },
  ```

Comment: А очереди не забыли настроить и запустить?

Comment: очереди зачем здесь можете пояснить ?

Answer (score 0):

Класс Test у Вас использует трейт Dispatchable, который и должен ставить поступающие задачи в очередь. Можете просмотреть незапущенные задачи в таблице jobs.
Очередь можно указать принудительно:

```
// App\Events\Test

public string $broadcastQueue = 'broadcast_queue';
```

а затем запустить очереди

```
artisan queue:work --queue=broadcast_queue
```

если используете хостинг, то для запуска очередей можно написать скрипт для крона.